# SD card, corrupted, data recovery, file type unrecognized, allocated memory not recognized, all data recovery software fails to even scan correctly

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, partition-recovery, file-recovery, micro-sd-card

I have a corrupted SD card and need help:

SD card from android says corrupted in phone.
Windows says it needs to be formatted.
Chkdsk says it cannot restore raw file format.

All file recovery systems do not work... card (32 GB) reads as 31MB with 31 MB unallocated RAW memory. Data recovery softwares including partition recovery software only checks the 31 MB thats empty anyway thus retrieves nothing as its already empty.

31 GB of data stored on sd card is invisible to all data recovery software and disk management software.(disk drill, recuva, easeus, test and photo rec cannot even see it as the memory needs to be recognized for them to begin recovery scan)

The missing 31 GB is the data I want to recover. But no software will attempt recovery because it treats the card as if the 31 MB thats empty RAW format unallocated space is the only memory on the card.
the data is very important to me. I want to recover it.

Any ideas or advice? I've checked everywhere and the same steps I've already tried are all I can find to attempt a fix except for doing a quick format and attempting a deleted file recovery afterwards which probably wont work anyway. (my guess is it will simply format the 31 MB unallocated empty space just like the scan only scans that empty memory when attempting recovery)

Comment: Seems the SD card is defective on the hardware layer, it is much less work to just restore from backup than to try any more steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a hardware defect, which you won't be able to fix (a commercial lab maybe is, depending on whether the storage cells or the additional hardware is defective).

Nevertheless: First create a 1:1 image backup of the drive e.g. by using http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/ or dd on Linux, and try restoration on that one. This is to conserve at least the current state and prevent further damage to your SD card, if you're planning to hand it over to a professional provider. The image size should be several GB (HDD-Raw-Copy compresses the image). If you're unable to bit-wise read the whole portition of data (and end up with your 30MB) I don't see that DIY recovery will be possible.

Try recovery on that image; you could give [GetDataBack](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-products.htm) a shot (don't know how far the free version will take you), they support recovery from image out of the box. For other recovery software (Recuva, PhotoRec, Disk Drill... depending on what you already tried) it may be necessary to [mount the image](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) first.

Comment: `ddrescue` (free, open source) is a **much better** tool to recommend on Linux than `dd` for making a image backup from a imperfect source device, as `ddrescue` is explicitly designed to get as much data as possible off a device that may be failing.